# Revert all svn:ignore properties recursively

Tags: svn, revert, svnignore

I've messed up some of my directories `svn:ignore` property.

How can I recursively revert all `svn:ignore` properties of all directories to the current version in SVN without reverting their containing files?

Comment: What do you mean by "revert"? Is there one commit where you set the property on all directories that you want to revert, or do you want to change the value of that property on all directories?  Just need a little more precision...

Comment: In the svn there are commits setting the property. I checked out these commits and changed files and properties locally. I now only want to revert the properties leaving the files as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of the directories you want to revert, and revert them (if you are on some kind of Unix, *and* don't use spaces in your paths):

```
svn st -q | \
awk '{print $2;}' | \
xargs svn pg svn:ignore | \
sed -n -e 's/ - .*$//p' | \
xargs svn revert --depth empty
```

If you are stuck on Windows, consider installing [GNU on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) and replace the `'` above by `"`.

If you just want to delete them, you can use

```
svn pd svn:ignore -R ...
```